# NestJS Reject POST Request With Bad Body (Validate POST Body Type)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I want to enforce type checking on my POST bodies. Simply checking to make sure the body a user entered has **some or all** of the properties of a given type.

I have complex types, like SalesOrder for example. It has objects that are nested, arrays of objects, etc. I want to allow the user to **POST only with certain properties from the parent object**

For example, let's say this is my full SalesOrder type:

```
export class SalesOrder {
    ID: number,
    DeliveryInfo: {
        ActualDeliveryDateTime: string
        ScheduledDeliveryDateTime: string
    }

    SalesOrderGeneralInfo: {
        Branch: IDValue
        InventoryLocation: IDValue
        SalesOrderClassification: IDValue
        Reference: string
    }

    SalesOrderInsuranceInfo: {
        CoverageVerified: string
        InsuranceVerified: string
        SignatureGeneratedByProvider: string
    }

}

interface IDValue {
    ID: string,
    Value: string;
}
```

I would like to allow users to Include in their post body a subset of these properties, currently represented by the type SalesOrderUpdate. Technically all of the properties in this class are optional:

```
export class SalesOrderUpdateDto {
    ID: number;
    SalesOrder: SalesOrderUpdate
}

export class SalesOrderUpdate {
    DeliveryInfo: {
        ActualDeliveryDateTime: string;
        ScheduledDeliveryDateTime: string;
    }

    SalesOrderGeneralInfo: {
        Branch: IDValue
        InventoryLocation: IDValue
        SalesOrderClassification: IDValue
        Reference: string;
    }

}
```

Now the key is, **they can send any number of the properties from the DTO type**
So if a user wanted to POST with only SalesOrderGeneralInfo.Branch.Value, that should be allowed. If they want to send the full body, that should be allowed.
But, if they want to send a POST with SalesOrderInsuranceInfo, that should be blocked. And if they wanted to send a POST with random properties placed everywhere, **that should definitely be blocked**. Currently, NestJS will allow literally anything in the POST body, which is insane to me.

Here is my basic controller:

```
@Post('/update')
async salesOrderUpdate(
@Body() body: SalesOrderUpdateDto,
) {
    return await this.salesOrderService.updateSalesOrder(`${body.ID}`, body.SalesOrder);
}
```

I tried using ValidationPipe on the controller:

```
@Post('/update')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }))
async salesOrderUpdate(
@Body() body: SalesorderUpdateDto,
```

Then I had to annotate the DTO:

```
export class SalesorderUpdateDto {
    @IsNumber()
    ID: number;

    @IsNotEmptyObject()
    @ValidateNested()
    SalesOrder: SalesOrderUpdate
}

export class SalesOrderUpdate {
    DeliveryInfo: {
        ActualDeliveryDateTime: string;
        ScheduledDeliveryDateTime: string;
    }
...
```

But this results in an empty SalesOrder Object. I feel like this should be very easy and simple to implement but the examples on Stack Overflow are unfortunately not helpful at all. I am **not interested** in creating 200 line long custom validators (hopefully this isn't necessary). All I care about that the structure of the POST body matched the type assigned to it, and for the request to fail if it does not

I just cannot believe that, by default, I can assign a type to a POST body and submit something *of a completely different type*, and NestJS will just carry on without error.

Comment: do notice that the validation (and transformation) process of parsed body is not up to Nest but to `class-validator` and `class-transformer`. Nest just handle what they'll throw when you use the built-in `ValidationPipe`, as you could see [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/1394305bf394654a0e2c72142b06bd29277718d9/packages/common/pipes/validation.pipe.ts#L195). You just need to enable this feat